# Invite friend on facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i invites friend on Facebook from my app.My friend gets notification like "my name invited you to try my app name : "Fghj"". I don't not know  where i added this text? Why this text showing ?

Comment: Please share some code which you write for inviting friend on Facebook. We can not help you by reading above 2 lines.

Comment: FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"app link url"];

    
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg"];
   [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self
                                     withContent:content
                                        delegate:self];

Comment: code seems right. Try to search for that text in your project may it getting appended somewhere